# Xamarin iOS - Disable Back up and Restore for Application

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I know Android and iOS can back up app’s data files, the backup data is then allowed to be transferred from old device to new device.

For android, I understand that we can disable backups for your application with `<application android:allowBackup="false" ...` in AndroidManifest.xml file. I wonder if iOS has the same?

Answer (score 2):

The backup scheme on iOS is more complicated than on android. There is no simple attribute such as `android:allowBackup="false"` to disable the backup feature globally.

we could use the [SetSkipBackupAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/foundation.nsfilemanager.setskipbackupattribute?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12)  function to control whether backup my files.

```
NSFileManager.SetSkipBackupAttribute (filename, true); // backup will be skipped for this file
```

Detailed info is [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/xamarin-docs/blob/live/docs/ios/app-fundamentals/file-system.md).

Answer (score -1):

In Flutter, you can use the flutter_secure_storage package to disable app data backup on iOS. This package provides the ability to store data securely in Keychain and disable its backup. To disable the backup of data stored in flutter_secure_storage, you need to manually set the kSecAttrAccessible property to kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlockThisDeviceOnly.

It might look like this:

final FlutterSecureStorage _secureStorage = const FlutterSecureStorage(iOptions:IOSOptions(accessibility: KeychainAccessibility.first_unlock_this_device) , aOptions: AndroidOptions(encryptedSharedPreferences: true), );

Comment: The question isn't regarding Flutter - it's about Xamarin iOS, which is a completely different mobile technology.